# Device pairing using private iOS BluetoothManager framework

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi

I've been messing around with the private BluetoothManager framework in iOS 5.0 and I've been able to successfully start/stop Bluetooth and get a list of devices, however I can't figure out how to initiate pairing.

The closest I've come is to try to connect using:

```
[[BluetoothManager sharedInstance] connectDevice:dev];
```

where **dev** is a BluetoothDevice object discovered during scanning.

This seems to attempt to pair (when I try to connect to my iMac, the pairing dialog appears for a split second), but then quickly fails.

I've noticed that the BluetoothManager.h includes a **BTPairingAgentImpl** struct which might help, but I have no idea of what this struct includes or how to use it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you found a way to connect to a bluetooth device? If yes, it would be great, if you could contact me. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the project that required that bluetooth connection got shelved so I haven't had a reason to keep messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is getting a BluetoothDevice object (see BluetoothDevice.h) and using its methods: pairing, connect , etc.

Comment: Late comment but: There is no "pairing" method on the device.  Just "connect" and "unpair".  Best I can determine, one must use a pairing agent to establish pairing but haven't been successful doing this yet.

Comment: bluetooth not use for Iphone 5s ,can you help me please